# Spark reading python3 pickle as input

Tags: python, apache-spark, serialization, pyspark, rdd

My data are available as sets of Python 3 pickled files. Most of them are serialization of Pandas `DataFrames`.

I'd like to start using Spark because I need more memory and CPU that one computer can have. Also, I'll use HDFS for distributed storage.

As a beginner, I didn't found relevant information explaining how to use pickle files as input file.

Does it exists? If not, are there any workaround?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A lot depends on the data itself. Generally speaking Spark doesn't perform particularly well when it has to read large, not splittable files. Nevertheless you can try to use `binaryFiles` method and combine it with the standard Python tools. Lets start with a dummy data:

```
import tempfile
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

outdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()

for i in range(5):
    pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.randn(10, 2), columns=['foo', 'bar']
    ).to_pickle(tempfile.mkstemp(dir=outdir)[1])
```

Next we can read it using `bianryFiles` method:

```
rdd = sc.binaryFiles(outdir)
```

and deserialize individual objects:

```
import pickle
from io import BytesIO

dfs = rdd.values().map(lambda p: pickle.load(BytesIO(p)))
dfs.first()[:3]

##         foo       bar
## 0 -0.162584 -2.179106
## 1  0.269399 -0.433037
## 2 -0.295244  0.119195
```

One important note is that it typically requires significantly more memory than a simple methods like `textFile`.

Another approach is to parallelize only the paths and use libraries which can read directly from a distributed file system like [hdfs3](https://github.com/dask/hdfs3/). This typically means lower memory requirements at the price of a significantly worse data locality.

Considering these two facts it is typically better to serialize your data in a format which can be loaded with a higher granularity.

**Note**:

`SparkContext` provides `pickleFile` method, but the name can be misleading. It can be used to read [`SequenceFiles`](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SequenceFile) containing pickle objects not the plain Python pickles.